# Services Similar to Cronless?

Tags: cron, curl

Are there any other well known cron alternative services to manage large amounts of automated tasks, such as curl'ng a url at a certain frequency?

The only one I have found is cronless.com

Comment: Explaining what you don't like about cron would help us give a more helpful answer.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at launchd. It's created by apple to replace all the startup & task services (init, cron, etc) on macos but there are ports for Linux & BSD.